# Hide GroupName based on String and Display Everything Else

Tags: string, crystal-reports, grouping

Running Crystal Reports 11. Trying to hide one Group Name "ABC" from my report while still displaying the rest of my data and GroupNames.

I have the current formula in "Selection Formulas -> Group Selection"

```
IF GroupName ({sql_sortname}) LIKE "ABC" THEN FALSE
ELSE TRUE
```

While it works great for what I need it do (I have another flag that displays a subreport based on "ABC" and also behaves), items that have "blank" or "null" GroupName disappear which is what I do not want.

I have tried many variations to get the blank/null {sql_sortname} to appear but to no avail. Asking to see if anyone out here has a solution.

Comment: Have you tried the isnull() function?

Comment: I have tried a few combinations. I have added "N/A" to my SQL and going to see if I can sort for that.

Comment: I resolved it, and the answer was simple:

GroupName ({sql_sortname}) <> "ABC"

Seems the IF statement was actually to blame along with a null value for a Group name which did some conditional formatting to remove the 'N/A'